# Simplifying Signal Flow Graph Using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, controls, block

I want to find a simple method to simplify signal flow graphs (sfg's) using MATLAB. I found [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33735-symbolic-reduction-of-block-diagrams-and-signal-flow-graphs), however, I don't understand what the M matrix is . Could some one explain to me what it is?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZktK.jpg)

```
syms G1 G2 G3 G4 G5 G6
M=[1  0  0  0  0  0 0 1 1  -1
 -G1  1  0  0  0  0 0 0 0  0
  0  -1  1  0  0  0 1 0 0  0
  0   0 -G2 1  0  0 0 0 0  0
  0   0  0 -1  1  1 0 0 0  0
  0   0  0  0  0  1 0 0 0 -G3
  0   0  0  0 -G4 0 1 0 0  0
  0   0  0  0 -G5 0 0 1 0  0
  0 -G6  0  0  0  0 0 0 1  0]

N=rref(M)
```

Comment: Looks like an adjacency matrix for the graph.

Comment: Thank. Adjacency matrix is square and almost diagonal elements of the matrix are all zero. It's 10x9. If it's adjacency matrix of the graph how can you explain it?